# Ошибка "Failed to find function EVP_md5"

Tags: lua

Мой луа код выглядит так:

```
local aes = require 'aes'
cipher = aes.encrypt('password', 'secret');
```

Когда я запускаю его с командной строки:

```
$ lua unit.lua
```

Я получаю такое сообщение об ошибки:

```
lua: /usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/aes.lua:106: failed to find function/global EVP_md5
stack traceback: 
    [C]: ? /usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/aes.lua:106: in main chunk 
    [C]: in function 'require' /usr/local/openresty/nginx/test/unit_tests.lua:4: in main chunk 
    [C]: ?
```

Что это за ошибка и как я ее могу исправить?

Comment: Есть смутное подозрение, что не хватает OpenSSL, больно имя функции похожее.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на библиотеку или её полное имя?